# How to make ComboBox column in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have `DataGridView` with 2 columns:

```
Fname | Age
```

I need to show `Age` in `ComboBox` (that i can pick the age between 1 to 100).
When I press the button (save button for example) the Age value will be saved to the database. (I work with access)

Can i get any sample in C# for this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check MSDN? It has a good example at [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a [`DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx)?

This "represents a column of [`DataGridViewComboBoxCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.aspx) objects", each of which display a ComboBox control in the DataGridView.

The above-linked MSDN documentation also has an example of how you might implement this. But it's even easier to do from the Visual Studio designer; you don't even have to write a single line of code.

Comment: can you help me to design and populate a column(Index 1) in a datagridview(winforms) which is a comboboxcolumn?

Answer (score -2):

```
string value = combodisease.SelectedItem.ToString();
string str = "select test, normal, high, cost from testname join testcost on testcost.testid=testname.testid where test='"+value+"'";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, cn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```